# No module named 'pymysql'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pymysql

I'm trying to use PyMySQL on Ubuntu.

I've installed `pymysql` using both `pip` and `pip3` but every time I use `import pymysql`, it returns `ImportError: No module named 'pymysql'`

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit and Python 3.5.

The same .py works on Windows with Python 3.5, but not on Ubuntu.

Comment: You ran `sudo pip3 install pymysql` then tried to `import pymysql` running `python3`?

Comment: Yup, i'm running it from sudo.

Comment: Odd, works just fine on my system. Try running `sudo apt-get install python3-pymysql`.

Comment: That's it! Thanks mate!

Comment: Answer is found, but It would be nice to learn why this happened.
Are you sure that `python3` and `sudo python3` are the same python?

Comment: These solutions didn't work for me, only Yash Gupta's suggestion (below) worked. I'm running ubuntu 14.04, Django 2.0, Python 3.6.

Comment: Same issue with Mac machine. pymysql is installed. but module error when we run python script. apt-get is not supported for mac. Used brew instead of apt-get but brew doesn't have package python3-pymysql

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Sort of already answered this in the comments, but just so this question has an answer, the problem was resolved through running:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pymysql
```

Comment: If the problem still not goes away, try this on debian systems, `apt install python-mysqldb`

Comment: Same issue with Mac machine. pymysql is installed. but module error when we run python script. apt-get is not supported for mac. Used brew instead of apt-get but brew doesn't have package python3-pymysql

Comment: This line of code made my day. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 35):

**Use:**

```
import pymysql
```

**Not:**

```
import PyMySQL
```

That works for me.

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 16.04 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.9.

Comment: Wish I could up-vote this twice. Such a silly mistake and contrary to any tutorial I've seen on this.

Comment: Ow DUDE. You saved my life. Worked on Debian 9

Comment: This ones the time-saver~

Answer (score 25):

After trying a few things, and coming across [PyMySQL Github](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL), this worked:

`sudo pip install PyMySQL`

And to import use:

`import pymysql`

Comment: This did not work on Mac. Install ok - Import not ok.

Comment: If you get the error: `awscli 1.15.47 has requirement PyYAML<=3.12,>=3.10, but you'll have pyyaml 4.1 which is incompatible.` Then you have dependency issues and have to run: `apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-pip libpython-dev` and `pip install awscli`

Answer (score 9):

To get around the problem, find out where pymysql is installed.

If for example it is installed in `/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages`, add the following code above the `import pymysql` command:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages")
import pymysql
```

This ensures that your Python program can find where pymysql is installed.

Answer (score 8):

If even `sudo apt-get install python3-pymysql` does not work for you try this:

- Go to [the PyMySQL page](http://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) and download the zip file.
- Then, via the terminal, cd to your Downloads folder and extract
  the folder
- cd into the newly extracted folder
- Install    the setup.py file with: `sudo python3 setup.py install`

Comment: The other solutions offered on this page didn't work for me, only this one. Thanks @Yash Gupta !

Comment: Neither this nor the above worked for me, will try a different connector

Answer (score 7):

1. Make sure that you're working with the version of Python that think you are. Within Python run `import sys` and `print(sys.version)`.
2. Select the correct package manager to install pymysql with:

   - For Python 2.x `sudo pip install pymysql`.
   - For Python 3.x `sudo pip3 install pymysql`.
   - For either running on Anaconda: `sudo conda install pymysql`.
   - If that didn't work try APT: `sudo apt-get install pymysql`.
3. If all else fails, install the package directly:

   - Go to the [PyMySQL page](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) and download the zip file.
   - Then, via the terminal, cd to your Downloads folder and extract the folder.
   - cd into the newly extracted folder.
   - Install the setup.py file with: `sudo python3 setup.py install`.

This answer is a compilation of suggestions. Apart from the other ones proposed here, thanks to the comment by @cmaher on [this related thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647617/modulenotfounderror-pymysql-for-python-3).

Answer (score 3):

fwiw, for a [conda env](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pymysql):

```
 conda install -c anaconda pymysql
```

Answer (score 2):

For windows or one using google colab, you can try this

```
!pip install pymysql
import pymysql
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to install:

```
python3 -m pip install PyMySQL
```

Answer (score 1):

The following `pymysql` version worked for me:

```
pip install pymysql==1.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install python3-pymysql`

This command also works for me to install the package required for Flask app to tun on ubuntu 16x with WISG module on APACHE2 server.

BY default on WSGI uses python 3 installation of UBUNTU.

Anaconda custom installation won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem just now, and found the reason was my editor (Visual Studio Code) was running against the wrong instance of python; I had it set to run again python bundled with tensorflow, I changed it to my Anaconda python and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem earlier, but solved it in a way slightly different from what we have here. So, I thought I'd add my way as well. Hopefully, it will help someone!

`sudo apt-get install mysql-client` didn't work for me. However, I have Homebrew already installed. So, instead, I tried:

```
brew install mysql-client
```

Now, I don't get the error any more.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note:
for Anaconda install packages command:

1. **python setup.py install**

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SPYDER IDE , just try to restart the console or restart the IDE, it works

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error recently when using Anaconda on a Mac machine.

Here is what I found:

1. After running `python3 -m pip install PyMySql,` pymysql module is under `/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages`
2. Anaconda wants this module to be under `/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages`

Therefore, after copying pymysql module to the designated path, it runs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing pymysql on command prompt by typing

```
pip install pymysql
```

But it still dont work on my case, so I decided to try using the terminal IDE and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another common issue causing the error message to appear is related to `conda` environments in `jupyter notebook` and `jupyter lab`.

After successfully installing a module (`pymysql` in this case) in one environment, `import` may seem to fail because the environment has not been correctly registered. To solve this it is necessary to manually add kernels for each environment.

Solution and more details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44786736/6332373).

Answer (score 0):

For anaconda user,

I got this error message.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'

So tried 'pip install pymysql' but got below.
Requirement already satisfied: pymysql

What worked for me is,

> **python** file.py (NOT **py** file.py)

Answer (score 0):

When attempting to execute c = connection.cursor() within the Python shell in the context of my Django project, I encountered the same error.

[image]

pymysql has already been installed using pip in my environment

[image]

I have discovered that it's essential to install the PyMySQL package using the Python interpreter associated with the project's environment. This ensures the package is correctly installed and readily available for import within the project's context.

To verify that you're using the correct Python interpreter, you can follow these steps

[image]

In my case, I am using Python 3.12.2, which corresponds to the command: C:\Users\brand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe.

Since I'm using Git Bash in VSCode, the appropriate command to install PyMySQL would be: C:/Users/brand/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe -m pip install pymysql. Executing this command in the Git Bash terminal will install the PyMySQL package.

[image]

I successfully resolved the issue by directly installing PyMySQL using the Python interpreter.

A Python shell is initiated within a Django project, facilitating the establishment of a database connection. This setup enables interaction with the database through Django's ORM (Object-Relational Mapper).

[image]