# pymysql no module problem on mac os (conda install solution didn't work)

Tags: sql, terminal, anaconda, conda, pymysql

I'm a mac os user (and also a programming beginner )
I installed pymysql package via pip but got an error message from jupyter notebook saying (no module found : pymysql)
After, searching through the link below
([ModuleNotFoundError - PyMySQL for python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647617/modulenotfounderror-pymysql-for-python-3)) I assumed that the problem was that I installed the package via pip while using conda.
so after reinstalling it via conda I got the message below from the terminal.
'Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## All requested packages already installed.'

However, when I tried to run the codes again with hopes, got the same message again (no module pymysql found). Now I'm a bit lost. What else can I try to fix no module pymysql problem ?

Comment: Are you using the Python IDE/ Jupiter Notebook  that Anaconda provides?

Comment: Yep I'm using the latest python version provided by anaconda 3