# Facing below error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'"

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Facing below error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'"

```
import os
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

host = os.getenv('MYSQL_HOST')
port = os.getenv('MYSQL_PORT')
user = os.getenv('MYSQL_USER')
password = os.getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD')
database = os.getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE')
```

Need assistance as I am new to this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you install pymysql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named 'pymysql'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446347/no-module-named-pymysql)

Comment: @Vanz How can I check the duplicate for the same

Answer (score 1):

This issue got fixed.
I installed pymysql and mysql-connector using anaconda prompt.

1. Open Anaconda Prompt
2. pip install mysql-connector
3. pip install pymysql

Answer (score 0):

make sure it's installed.

run this in terminal/cmd:

windows

```
$ python3 -m pip install PyMySQL
```

or simply:

```
pip install PyMySQL
```

linux

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pymysql
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback!!
But I am still facing the same error

Comment: are you using virtual environment? try installing it there.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on my pc too it took me 1 day :) So go to your cmd or terminal and write : pip uninstall pymysql

python -m pip --upgrade pip pip install pymysql

This will fix it as the version of pip u are using cant build a wheel for the module