# No Module named “PyMySQL” Windows 10

Tags: mysql, pymysql

I installed the pymysql module, and I get this error "No Module named“ PyMySQL ”Windows 10" working on Pycharm really need help

Comment: I think this question has already been answered at [No module named 'pymysql'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446347/no-module-named-pymysql)

Comment: they ask about Ubuntu and I need help with Windows 10